# php counting button clicks

Tags: php, html

I making a tic tac toe game I have this button, but I could like to count the number of times a user clicks it that way I can use it as my tie game condition when clicks = 8 and no winner has been determined. How do I pass and increment the number of times I click this button?

do I use the javascript onclick event?

```
print('<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value = "Go">');


if(isset($_POST[submit_button])) 
{
do stuff

}
```

Comment: `submit_button` should be `"submit_button"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP won't solve your problem here, as it is only server side.  Declare a variable `numClicks` in your JavaScript, and change the `input` to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" onclick="increaseClicks()" value = "Go">
```

Then you can define `increaseClicks` to be

```
function increaseClicks(){
    numClicks++;
    if(numClicks >= 8){
        //dostuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I think pass the variables back into my php script? Because all my game logic is being done server side.

Comment: If you wish to pass data back to the server, then I'd suggest AJAX.  Though doing some of the game logic client-side would be much faster.

Comment: agree with someKittens unless you want to store the number click for each user in the database, client script should handle the clicks and at the end send results to server to save game score or something